# In pyparsing, Each doesn't match every element inside it regardless of order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyparsing

There is certainly the possibility I'm completely misunderstanding what `Each` does, but from what I understand (from the documentation):

> Requires all given ParseExpressions to be found, but in any order. Expressions may be separated by whitespace.

I tried to do this:

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
>>> foobar = Each([Word('foo'), Word('bar')])
>>> foobar.parseString('foobar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1162, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1152, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1018, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2638, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring,loc,"Missing one or more required elements (%s)" % missing )
pyparsing.ParseException: Missing one or more required elements (W:(bar)) (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
>>> foobar.parseString('foo bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1162, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1152, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1018, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2638, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring,loc,"Missing one or more required elements (%s)" % missing )
pyparsing.ParseException: Missing one or more required elements (W:(bar)) (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
>>> foobar.parseString('bar foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1162, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1152, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1018, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 2638, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring,loc,"Missing one or more required elements (%s)" % missing )
pyparsing.ParseException: Missing one or more required elements (W:(foo)) (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

The first `foobar.parseString('foobar')` definitely should have thrown an exception, but the other two should not have, unless I'm missing something. If I replace line 2 with foobar = Word('foo') & Word('bar') as suggested in the documentation, I get the same results.

This is python 3 btw.

As a side note, the example given here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/web/class-Each.html

Does not seem functional with the same error message.

Interestingly enough, `foobar = Optional('foo') & Optional('bar')` does seem to work properly, with the caveat that it also matches 'foo' and 'bar' by themselves. Why is this?

Comment: A bug in Each was introduced in version 2.1.0. Version 2.1.1 can be retrieved from SVN on Sourceforge, and I will be pushing it up to PyPI in the next day or so.

Comment: Just released version 2.1.1, with this bugfix.